# javascript (dom) nth-chld() returns null?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<!--This is in in the body section.--!>
<div id="par">
<p id="p1"><h3>paragraphs</h3>/p>
<p id="p2">paragraph 1</p>
<p id="p3">paragraph 2</p>
<p id="p4">paragraph 3</p>
<p id="p5">paragraph 4</p>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

var x = document.querySelector("#div11 p:nth-child(2)");
document.write(x);

</script>
```

This html code returns null. However, it works fine when I remove the < h3> tags from the first paragraph.
Can someone please explain why it behaves in this way?

Comment: Here you've got a div with id `par`, but in your call to `querySelector` you are asking for an element with id `div11`. Where is that div?

Comment: In addition to @OscarPaz: that's not valid HTML. Your first `p` tag is not closed correctly.

Comment: nth-child(2) will look for the second element of it parent so when you added an h3 theire will be no second element nth-child(2) also you have an enclosing tag missing and their is no element with the id div11

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif That is not true, the `h3` has nothing to do with whether a `p` is `nth-child` or not.

Comment: @LGSon he has an h3 element inside a p element wish is totaly wrong how it will be able to find the second element of the p tag ?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif Exactly...which I explained in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is invalid using block elements inside a `<p>` tag, so changing it to e.g. a `span` and it works (and use the correct `id` for the `div`).

Stack snippet

```js
var x = document.querySelector("#par p:nth-child(2)");
console.log(x.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="par">
  <p id="p1"> <span>paragraphs</span> </p>
  <p id="p2">paragraph 1</p>
  <p id="p3">paragraph 2</p>
  <p id="p4">paragraph 3</p>
  <p id="p5">paragraph 4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `querySelectorAll` to get all matches:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div p:nth-child(2)");

console.log(x);
```

```html
<!--This is in in the body section.--!>
<div id="par">
  <p id="p1"><h3>paragraphs</h3>/p>
  <p id="p2">paragraph 1</p>
  <p id="p3">paragraph 2</p>
  <p id="p4">paragraph 3</p>
  <p id="p5">paragraph 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: As `querySelectorAll` returns a _NodeList_, one need to iterate is result, even if there will be only 1 (or use `x[0]` to get the first) ... and still, this won't give any result for the reason I stated in my answer.